# HTML Row spacing is not correct

Tags: html

i've the below HTML page containing 2 2 tables in  1 main table.

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : P2
    Created on : Mar 7, 2013, 1:19:55 PM
    Author     : u0138039
--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <table width="722">
            <tr>
              <td width="334">
              <table width="255" >
                <tr>
                  <td width="128"><p>PARTS Updated&#13;</p></td>
                  <td width="111"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label>
                    <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><p>TSI OK&#13;</p></td>
                  <td><label for="TSI_OK"></label>
                    <select name="TSI_OK" id="TSI_OK">
                      <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                      <option value="TSI Query">TSI Query</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><p>Special Ins OK&#13;</p></td>
                  <td><label for="Special_Ins_OK"></label>
                    <select name="Special_Ins_OK" id="Special_Ins_OK">
                      <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                      <option value="SI Query">SI Query</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="376"><table width="279" align="center" height="44">
                <tr>
                  <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
                  <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID"></label>
                  <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i'm commenting out the below part

```
<%-- 
    Document   : P2
    Created on : Mar 7, 2013, 1:19:55 PM
    Author     : u0138039
--%>
```

i am getting the table as i wanted, but when i uncomment it the row space is changing, i.e. it is increasing. please let me know how to make the row space reduced and comment the above mentioned part.

Thanks

Comment: why is this section outside the body tag...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Code:

```
<%-- Part 1 (Replace % with ! for HTML comment)
    Document   : P2
    Created on : Mar 7, 2013, 1:19:55 PM
    Author     : u0138039
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%-- Part 2 (Replace % with ! for HTML comment)
   Document   : P2
   Created on : Mar 7, 2013, 1:19:55 PM
   Author     : u0138039
-->

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="722" border=1>
        <tr>
          <td width="334">
          <table width="255"  border=1>
            <tr>
              <td width="128"><p>PARTS Updated&#13;</p></td>
              <td width="111"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label>
                <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>TSI OK&#13;</p></td>
              <td><label for="TSI_OK"></label>
                <select name="TSI_OK" id="TSI_OK">
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                  <option value="TSI Query">TSI Query</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>Special Ins OK&#13;</p></td>
              <td><label for="Special_Ins_OK"></label>
                <select name="Special_Ins_OK" id="Special_Ins_OK">
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                  <option value="SI Query">SI Query</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
          <td width="376"><table width="279" align="center" height="44" border=1>
            <tr>
              <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
              <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID"></label>
              <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Case 1: If you commenting "Part1" and "Part2". Then:
[image]

Case 2: If you uncommenting "Part1" and commenting "Part2". Then:
[image]

Case 3: If you commenting "Part1" and uncommenting "Part2". Then:
[image]

Because the ***"DOCTYPE html"*** declaration is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In Case2 the first line is not this ***"DOCTYPE html"*** so web-browser not able to know the version on html, so it will not able to format the rest tag.

In Case3 the first line is this ***"DOCTYPE html"*** so web-browser able to know the version on html, so it will able to format the rest tag. So we are getting the formatted table.

Comment: bro can you please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269516/unable-to-get-elements-passed-from-html -thanks