# unable to get elements passed from html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i'm having the below jsp page created.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function show(x)
        {
            document.getElementById(x).style.display='block';
        }
    function hide(x)
        {
            document.getElementById(x).style.display='none';
        }
        function handleKeyEvent(e) {
    var charCode;


    if (e && e.which) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else if (window.event) {
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if (charCode == 13) {
        //document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
        var m=document.getElementById(e);
        alert(m);
                hide(x);
    }
}


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="abc.jsp">
          <table width="722">
            <tr>
              <td width="431" height="190">
              <table width="439" >
                <tr>
                  <td width="129">PARTS Updated</td>
                  <td width="108"><p>
                    <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                    </select>
                  </p></td>
                  <td width="186"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>TSI OK&#13;</td>
                  <td><p>
                          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_N/A" value="TSI_N/A" onClick="hide('TSI_Query_Box')">
                    N/A
                  </p>
                  <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_Query" value="TSI_Query" onClick="show('TSI_Query_Box')">              TSI Query</p></td>
                  <td><label for="TSI_Query_Box"></label>
                      <textarea name="TSI_Query_Box" id="TSI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="handleKeyEvent('TSI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="65">Special Ins OK&#13;</td>
                  <td><p>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_N/A" value="TSI_OK" onClick="hide('SI_Query_Box')">
                    N/A
                  </p>
                    <p>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_Query" value="SI_Query" onClick="show('SI_Query_Box')"> SI Query</p></td>
                  <td><label for="SI_Query_Box"></label>
                      <textarea name="SI_Query_Box" id="SI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="handleKeyEvent('SI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="279">
                  <table width="279" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
                  <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID"></label>
                  <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <table width="721" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td width="374" align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" id="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" value="Send for CT Review (SCTR)"></td>
              <td width="331" align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="CT Review Complete (CTRC" id="CT Review Complete (CTRC)" value="CT Review Complete (CTRC)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="Cleanup Queries" id="Cleanup Queries" value="Cleanup Queries"></td>
              <td align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="Cleanup  Complete" id="Cleanup  Complete" value="Cleanup  Complete"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Go_To_Main_Page" id="Go_To_Main_Page" value="Go To Main Page"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

i wanted to see when i enter the text in textarea and hit enter, i want to see the text assed. in the present case it is alerting a message  [object]. Also when i check radio buttons, if i check TSI Query Radio button followed SI Query Radio button or vice versa, both are getting displayed, i want only one textarea to be displayed once.

for screenshot you can have a look at this link

http://jsfiddle.net/dYy26/

Thanks.

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: 1)here when i enter some data in textarea and hit an enter i want to see what the data in alert message, but is showing as [object] in textarea. 2) i want only 1 textarea to be revealed but when i select the second section radio button even the first section text area is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function show(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('Ship_IDl').style.display='block';
    }
function hide(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('Ship_IDl').style.display='none';
    }
function handleKeyEvent(e) {
var charCode;
if (e && e.which) {
    charCode = e.which;
} else if (window.event) {
    e = window.event;
    charCode = e.keyCode;
}
if (charCode == 13) {
    //document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
    var m=document.getElementById(e);
    alert(m);
            hide(x);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="abc.jsp">
      <table width="722">
        <tr>
          <td width="431" height="190">
          <table width="439" >
            <tr>
              <td width="129">PARTS Updated</td>
              <td width="108"><p>
                <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </p></td>
              <td width="186"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>TSI OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_N/A" value="TSI_N/A" onClick="hide('TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
              <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_Query" value="TSI_Query" onClick="show('TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')">              TSI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="TSI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="TSI_Query_Box" id="TSI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="handleKeyEvent('TSI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="65">Special Ins OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_N/A" value="TSI_OK" onClick="hide('SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
                <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_Query" value="SI_Query" onClick="show('SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')"> SI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="SI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="SI_Query_Box" id="SI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="handleKeyEvent('SI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
          <td width="279">
              <table width="279" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
              <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID"></label>
              <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="721" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="374" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" id="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" value="Send for CT Review (SCTR)"></td>
          <td width="331" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="CT Review Complete (CTRC" id="CT Review Complete (CTRC)" value="CT Review Complete (CTRC)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup Queries" id="Cleanup Queries" value="Cleanup Queries"></td>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup  Complete" id="Cleanup  Complete" value="Cleanup  Complete"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Go_To_Main_Page" id="Go_To_Main_Page" value="Go To Main Page"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code is fine but when i select N/A that textbox should be hidden

Comment: hey i've fixed it. not a problem. i want to know about this event thing. please help me.

Comment: thanks for that. but the main problem is with event handling. please see function handleKeyEvent(e) for the idea. enter text in that textarea and hit an enter -thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function show(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('Ship_IDl').style.display='block';
    }
function hide(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('Ship_IDl').style.display='none';
    }

function myKeyPress(e,x,y){
    var keynum;
    if(window.event){ // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }else
    if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    //alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    //alert(keynum);
    if (keynum == 13) {
        //document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
        var m=document.getElementById(x).value;
        alert(m);
        hide(x,y);
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="abc.jsp">
      <table width="722">
        <tr>
          <td width="431" height="190">
          <table width="439" >
            <tr>
              <td width="129">PARTS Updated</td>
              <td width="108"><p>
                <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </p></td>
              <td width="186"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>TSI OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_N/A" value="TSI_N/A" onClick="hide('TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
              <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_Query" value="TSI_Query" onClick="show('TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')">              TSI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="TSI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="TSI_Query_Box" id="TSI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none"  onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event,'TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="65">Special Ins OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_N/A" value="TSI_OK" onClick="hide('SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
                <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_Query" value="SI_Query" onClick="show('SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')"> SI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="SI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="SI_Query_Box" id="SI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event,'SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')""></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
          <td width="279">
              <table width="279" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
              <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID" id="Ship_IDl"></label>
              <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="721" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="374" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" id="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" value="Send for CT Review (SCTR)"></td>
          <td width="331" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="CT Review Complete (CTRC" id="CT Review Complete (CTRC)" value="CT Review Complete (CTRC)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup Queries" id="Cleanup Queries" value="Cleanup Queries"></td>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup  Complete" id="Cleanup  Complete" value="Cleanup  Complete"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Go_To_Main_Page" id="Go_To_Main_Page" value="Go To Main Page"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks bro. if you don't mind can i have your gmail id so that i can contact you whenever i post a question. thanks

Comment: hey here i've one more last question. how do i pass the textarea parameters to my jsp? i want in such a way that there are 2 textboxes in my jsp and when i fill textarea 1 text box1 in jsp should show that value leaving second as null and if textarea2 is filled the textbox2 in jsp should be filled and the other textbox should be shown as null. actually i want these parameters to update my database. Thanks